# Is there any standard for modern browsers showing/hiding the URL protocol within a browser’s URL area/omnibox?

Tags: urls, hidden

This post is sparked by [this recent post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1453659/167207) as well as [this other SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/q/1333575/167207) from 2018 on the same topic.

Basically, some modern web browsers purposefully obfuscate (aka: hide) the URL scheme by default nowadays. While I understand the desire to simplify the web for non-tech user’s, I—as a software developer and  systems administrator—find it to be a bit confusing.

Not only is it odd to see one browser display URLs in a different way from other browsers, in all cases, when I copy and paste the URL from a browser to a text file or the Terminal (in macOS) I see the full URL including the URL scheme/protocol.

So is obfuscating the URL scheme/protocol somehow as standardized UX practice for modern browsers? Meaning if I decide to create “Jakescape Navigator 2020” would I have to follow some established formatting for the omnibox/URL area?

Screenshots below of what I am seeing on macOS Mojave (10.14.5).

---

<sup>Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)</sup>

[image: Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)]

---

<sup>Safari 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)</sup>

[image: Safari 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)]

---

<sup>Opera 62.0.3331.18</sup>

[image: Opera 62.0.3331.18]

---

<sup>Firefox 67.0.4 (64-bit)</sup>

[image: Firefox 67.0.4 (64-bit)]

Comment: I think you've answered your own question :). Your examples show a clear lack of standard for how the URL gets displayed.

Comment: As a good practice, it will be good to show the protocol when you are editing the url. For long urls, subpage details are usually hidden. (just observation)

Comment: How the link looks in different browsers is the result of the user's settings.

Answer (score 1):

As your screen shots have illustrated, there is no standard for how the URL should be displayed in the omnibox.  However, some browsers (including Edge and Firefox) hide the `http` protocol but display the `https` protocol by default.  For Firefox, see the documentation for the [browser.urlbar.trimURLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.urlbar.trimURLs) preference for more information.